# Why in React js Map() method is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I use console.log it is printing all values perfectly and also if I pass these props one by one then it works perfectly fine but this map is not working her is my code:

` import Card from './Components/Card';
import './App.css'

```
const data = [
  {
    id : "1",
    title : "DARK",
    image : require("./Images/potrait1.jpg")
  },
  {
    id : "2",
    title : "DARK",
    image : require("./Images/potrait8.jpg")
  },
  {
    id : "3",
    title : "DARK",
    image : require("./Images/potrait4.jpg")
  },
  {
    id : "4",
    title : "DARK",
    image : require("./Images/potrait5.jpg")
  },
  {
    id : "5",
    title : "DARK",
    image : require("./Images/potrait6.jpg")
  },
  {
    id : "6",
    title : "DARK",
    image : require("./Images/potrait7.jpg")
  }
]

let App = ()=>{

{data.map((val)=>{

      return(
            <Card
              key = {val.id} 
              title = {val.title}
              image = {val.image}
            />
        );

  })}
}

export default App;
```

`

Comment: `App` doesn't have a return statement, so it's not going to render anything. Did you mean to wrap this in, say, `return (<div>/* map statement here*/</div>)`?

Comment: let App = ()=>(<>
  {data.map((val)=><Card
            key = {val.id} 
            title = {val.title}
            image = {val.image}
          />)}
</>)

Answer (score 0):

Replace {} with (). Try this

```
    let App = ()=> (
    {data.map((val)=>{

      return(
        <Card
          key = {val.id} 
          title = {val.title}
          image = {val.image}
        />
      );

     })}
```

)